# How to sync a local database in a WPF project to an online Azure database

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I am working on a WPF C# window application project. The project has its own local SQL database and my Azure server also has a database with the same details.

If I add an entry or edit an entry to the local SQL database, I would like it to be synced to the remote database.

How do I set up the project to sync the 2 databases?

Comment: Is the local database a localdb or a SQL Server Express Edition?

Comment: It was created as an SQL Server Database from the Visual Studio solution's project.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, replication is the most trusted one:

Replication is a set of technologies for copying and distributing data and database objects from one database to another and then synchronizing between databases to maintain consistency. Use replication to distribute data to different locations and to remote or mobile users over local and wide area networks, dial-up connections, wireless connections, and the Internet.

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transactional-replication

Also you can look at Azure data Sync in the below doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

Let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean I need to install additional tools to replicate the databases? Would it be possible to perform the sync just from the project?

Comment: SQL server is must for replication,You can check this step by step guide for the same : https://www.ifi.tech/transactional-replication-from-on-premise-sql-server-to-azure-sql-database/

Comment: Thanks Mohit. This is a good start. Do you recommend installing SQL Server 2017 Developer version or Express version?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync). Although you will need to install SQL Data Sync Agent as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-data-sync-agent) because the SQL Data Sync service communicates with SQL Server databases via the client agent. This security feature prevents direct communication with databases behind a firewall. When the SQL Data Sync service communicates with the agent, it does so using encrypted connections and a unique token or agent key,

You should define Sync Groups when using SQL Data Sync where you specify which tables you want to synchronize but each table needs to have a primary key. If your tables do not have a primary key, then SQL Data Sync cannot be used in this scenario.

You can schedule a Sync Group to synchronize every 5 minutes.

Comment: Is it possible to add the local database from the WPF application project to the Client Sync Agent? The guide does not clearly show it.

Comment: There is no way to interact with Azure Data sync using REST API, PowerShell or from a program. You need to manually configure SQL Data Sync using Azure portal and the Sync Agent.

Comment: After setting up the Sync Agent, where can I find the instance of the on-premise database on my PC? I want my application to update this database directly before it is synced to the SQL Azure database.